# Apache Avro SchemaParseException: Illegal Initial Character in Schema Definition

Tags: avro

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently facing an issue with Apache Avro while trying to configure a sink in my application. When I attempt to parse my schema, I'm encountering a `SchemaParseException` related to an illegal initial character. Here's the exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "lakehouse-io-1-1" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal initial character: {"type":"record","name":"blah_schema","fields":[{"name":"blah_string","type":"string"},{"name":"blah_int","type":"int"}]}
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.validateName(Schema.java:1562)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.access$400(Schema.java:91)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Name.<init>(Schema.java:701)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Names.get(Schema.java:1528)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1636)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1430)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1418)
        at org.apache.pulsar.ecosystem.io.lakehouse.sink.SinkWriter.parseRecordSchema(SinkWriter.java:124)
        at org.apache.pulsar.ecosystem.io.lakehouse.sink.SinkWriter.run(SinkWriter.java:203)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The schema I'm using is as follows:

```json
{"type":"record","name":"blah_schema","fields":[{"name":"blah_string","type":"string"},{"name":"blah_int","type":"int"}]}
```

From my understanding, the schema seems to be correctly formatted, adhering to Avro's naming conventions. However, the error suggests there's an issue with the initial character in the schema definition. I've checked for any surrounding characters or encoding issues but haven't found anything out of the ordinary.

I'm looking for insights on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can spot something wrong with my schema definition?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried a few different approaches to resolve the issue:

1. **Testing with Different Schemas**: I experimented with various schemas in a similar format to see if the problem was specific to this particular schema. However, the issue persisted across different schema definitions.
2. **Encoding Verification**: I checked the encoding of the schema file and confirmed it's UTF-8. This is important because Avro requires the schema to be in UTF-8 format, and any deviation could potentially lead to parsing errors.
3. **Schema Accuracy**: The schema I provided in the question is exactly what I'm passing to the parser. There are no additional characters or modifications being made to it before parsing.

Despite these efforts, the problem remains unresolved. The schema appears to be correctly formatted and encoded, yet the parser throws a `SchemaParseException`. I'm still looking for any potential reasons why this might be happening and would appreciate any further insights.

Comment: It sounds like maybe it's evaluating the schema you provided as a string and so it thinks the `{` is the first character in the schema name and throws the error due to that.

Answer (score 0):

It was evaluated as a String instead of JSON

Comment: How did you resolve that?

Comment: I realized that my frontend application has been sending requests with a String format instead of JSON. As a result, the backend has been encountering errors due to illegal characters.